# "What on earth made/had you do that"

Tags: word-choice, causatives, animacy

When are we suppose to use "made" and "had" in a sentence?

I know that *have* is a causative which means 'make'.  For example:

> He **had** me wait for five minutes at the shop.

So in the same way can we use **had** instead of **made**?  For example:

> What on the earth **had** you do that?

If not, why not?

Comment: Interesting question! One of the reasons I like ELL is because learners sometimes ask about usage quirks that native speakers simply don't tend to notice. In the specific example in the title, ***had*** is totally "non-idiomatic" in any context I can imagine. But even though this is partly because ***What*** implies a *thing* rather than a *person*, that's not the whole story. I'm not too keen on, say, *Who had you wait at the shop? Was it the sales assistant, or the store manager?* I look forward to seeing an informative answer here.

Answer (score 1):

"Have" and "make" have different meanings based on the intent, so context is very important, and there will be people who use them interchangeably.

> to make *someone* do *something*

is to force them against their will to do *something* with prior intent and is synonymous with *force*

> I made the kids eat all their vegetables.
>   *I forced the kids to eat all their vegetables*

whereas

> to have *someone* do *something*

is usually less forceful than being "made" to do something and can be synonymous with *ask*

> He *had* me wait since the delay *made* him late.
>   *he asked me to wait since the delay forced him to be late*

Your example

> What... *had* you do that?
>   *what had happened to cause you to do that*

is understandable, but not really used.  More often it's said

> What caused you to do that?
>   What made you do that?